# React Native navigator ref property

Tags: facebook, google-oauth, react-native, navigator

I am trying to follow the example (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/Examples/UIExplorer/Navigator) on the react native site to set up my navigator, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Right now I am having trouble with the ref property, as when its calls `_setNavigatorRef`, I am getting an error that it cannot find the `property _navigator of null` in the following code. It works in the example but I am not sure why:

**index.ios.js**

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var DataEntry = require('./app/DataEntry');
var PasswordView = require('./app/PasswordView');
var GoogSignIn = require('./app/GoogSignIn');


var {
    AppRegistry,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    Navigator,
    TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

class PasswordRecovery extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
        ref={this._setNavigatorRef}
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{id: 'GoogSignIn', name: 'Index'}}
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={(route) => {
          if (route.sceneConfig) {
            return route.sceneConfig;
          }
          return Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromRight;
        }} />
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
    switch (route.id) {
    case 'GoogSignIn':
      return <GoogSignIn navigator={navigator} />;
    case 'DataEntry':
      return <DataEntry navigator={navigator} />;
    case 'PasswordView':
      return <PasswordView navigator={navigator} />;
    default:
      return this.noRoute(navigator);
  }

  noRoute(navigator) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'stretch', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}
            onPress={() => navigator.pop()}>
          <Text style={{color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>ERROR: NO ROUTE DETECTED</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }

  _setNavigatorRef(navigator) {
    if (navigator !== this._navigator) {
      this._navigator = navigator;

      if (navigator) {
        var callback = (event) => {
          console.log(
            `TabBarExample: event ${event.type}`,
            {
              route: JSON.stringify(event.data.route),
              target: event.target,
              type: event.type,
            }
          );
        };
        // Observe focus change events from the owner.
        this._listeners = [
          navigator.navigationContext.addListener('willfocus', callback),
          navigator.navigationContext.addListener('didfocus', callback),
        ];
      }
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._listeners && this._listeners.forEach(listener => listener.remove());
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('PasswordRecovery', () => PasswordRecovery);
```

I am just trying to get this all setup so that I can display a Google Sign in scene and then navigate from there.  The code for that scene so far is here:

**GoogSignIn.js**

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var { NativeAppEventEmitter } = require('react-native');
var GoogleSignin = require('react-native-google-signin');
var cssVar = require('cssVar');
var { Icon } = require('react-native-icons');

var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  PixelRatio,
  Navigator,
} = React;

var NavigationBarRouteMapper = {

  LeftButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    if (index === 0) {
      return null;
    }

    var previousRoute = navState.routeStack[index - 1];
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigator.pop()}
        style={styles.navBarLeftButton}>
        <Text style={[styles.navBarText, styles.navBarButtonText]}>
          {previousRoute.title}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  },

  RightButton: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      null
    );
  },

  Title: function(route, navigator, index, navState) {
    return (
      <Text style={[styles.navBarText, styles.navBarTitleText]}>
        GOOGLE SIGN IN
      </Text>
    );
  },

};

class GoogSignin extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
var navigator = this.props.navigator;
var callback = (event) => {
  console.log(
    `NavigationBarSample : event ${event.type}`,
    {
      route: JSON.stringify(event.data.route),
      target: event.target,
      type: event.type,
    }
  );
};

// Observe focus change events from this component.
this._listeners = [
  navigator.navigationContext.addListener('willfocus', callback),
  navigator.navigationContext.addListener('didfocus', callback),
];
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this._listeners && this._listeners.forEach(listener => listener.remove());
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._configureOauth(
      '105558473349-7usegucirv10bruohtogd0qtuul3kkhn.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    );
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator) {
      console.log("HERE");
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {this._signIn(); }}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: '#f44336', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <View style={{padding: 12, borderWidth: 1/2, borderColor: 'transparent', borderRightColor: 'white'}}>
                <Icon
                  name='ion|social-googleplus'
                  size={24}
                  color='white'
                  style={{width: 24, height: 24}}
                />
              </View>
              <Text style={{color: 'white', padding: 12, marginTop: 2, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>Sign in with Google</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        </View>
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Navigator
      debugOverlay={false}
      style={styles.appContainer}
      renderScene={this.renderScene}
      navigationBar={
        <Navigator.NavigationBar
          routeMapper={NavigationBarRouteMapper}
          style={styles.navBar}/>
      }/>
    );
  }

  _configureOauth(clientId, scopes=[]) {
    console.log("WE HERE")
    GoogleSignin.configure(clientId, scopes);

    NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('googleSignInError', (error) => {
      console.log('ERROR signin in', error);
    });

    NativeAppEventEmitter.addListener('googleSignIn', (user) => {
      console.log(user);
      this.setState({user: user});
    });

    return true;
  }

  _signIn() {
    GoogleSignin.signIn();
  }

  _signOut() {
    GoogleSignin.signOut();
    this.setState({user: null});
  }
};

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  messageText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
    padding: 15,
    marginTop: 50,
    marginLeft: 15,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 15,
    borderBottomWidth: 1 / PixelRatio.get(),
    borderBottomColor: '#CDCDCD',
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 17,
    fontWeight: '500',
  },
  navBar: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  navBarText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
  navBarTitleText: {
    color: cssVar('fbui-bluegray-60'),
    fontWeight: '500',
    marginVertical: 9,
  },
  navBarLeftButton: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
  },
  navBarRightButton: {
    paddingRight: 10,
  },
  navBarButtonText: {
    color: cssVar('fbui-accent-blue'),
  },
  scene: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#EAEAEA',
  },
});



module.exports = GoogSignin;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's a context issue.  On your Navigator component, try converting from this:

`ref={this._setNavigatorRef}`

To this:

`ref={(navigator) => this._setNavigatorRef(navigator)}` (prettier IMHO)

or this:

`ref={this._setNavigatorRef.bind(this)}`

Comment: thank you, that worked, but now it gets to the console.log("HERE") in the GoogSignIn.js, and should be displaying a view, but the screen is blank.  Do you have any idea why this would be happening? I tried changing the route to another file, but the same thing happens, So I assume it must be something I've done on the Navigator originally

Comment: It's hard to say.  I don't see anything that jumps out.  It could be outside of the Navigator itself where that issue lies.  Have you tried injecting some <Text> elements around the Navigator to find the point at which it stops displaying things?  That is, have you proven that the issue is that the Navigator doesn't display stuff and not that the Navigator itself is not being displayed?  Could be that you need to set `flex:1` on some parent container that contains the navigator itself?

Comment: Had the flex on, still havent been able to figure it out... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34050852/react-native-navigator-screen-always-blank/34060649#34060649 started a question about that here instead